# PHP on pageload, MYSQL, or cronjob - which to use for checking if time has passed?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm making a checklist where items can be clicked again after a period of time.  Each user (potentially up to 1 million, but likely between 10,000 - 100,000) will have up to 200 items (probably split into chucks of less than 20 on different ajax tabs) on their checklist that all update after different intervals of time - some at 2 min 30 sec, some at 1 hour, some at 20 hours, and the tricky ones that reset at a specific time rather than an interval (I'm thinking cronjob for the specific time items).

My database rows will look something like:

```
---------------------------------------------
| UserID |  D1  |  D2  |  D3  |  D4  | D150 |
---------------------------------------------
| 345    | time | time | time | time | time |
| 7294   | time | time | time | time | time |
| 2385   | time | time | time | time | time |
---------------------------------------------
```

I plan on saving the reset times with something like:

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO checklists (D1) 
VALUES ((SYSDATE() + INTERVAL 20 HOUR))") 
or die (mysql_error());
```

I thought using SYSDATE() would be better than using NOW() since I read that NOW() uses the time it's inserted, rather than called, which if there are locked rows or something NOW() wouldn't be accurate enough for this (unless I have it backwards?). Info on this here:https://coderwall.com/p/eslwuw/why-not-to-use-now-in-mysql. Accuracy to the millisecond doesn't matter here, but accuracy to the second does.

So, after I have the reset time saved into the database with the above code, what is the most efficient way to show an accurate up-to-date checklist on the page?

Do I use `SELECT * FROM checklists WHERE D1 < NOW()` on pageload with the UserID to limit the search, some kind of PHP script on pageload, or run a cronjob several times a minute (I doubt this is an appropriate method but figured I should include it anyways)?

Which method of checking is better for having fast page loading times?  Which will put more stress on the server?

Would it be better to have 100 different tables with the lists split into chunks to match tab contents like:

```
-----------------    -----------------    -----------------         
| UserID |  D1  |    | UserID |  D2  |    | UserID |  D10 |        
-----------------    -----------------    -----------------         
| 345    | time |    | 345    | time |    | 345    | time |
| 7294   | time |    | 7294   | time |    | 7294   | time |
| 2385   | time |    | 2385   | time |    | 2385   | time |
-----------------    -----------------    -----------------
```

More info:
The user's page will have tabs with 10-20 of the checklist items on each tab.
The user will click a button to show they finished a task which is when the reset time will be added to the database.
When they reload the tab it will show if any of the checklist items are ready to be clicked again.

Comment: _“since I read that NOW() uses the time it's inserted, rather than called”_ – that’s not correct. Only difference is that `NOW` is the timestamp at which a statement _began_ to execute, whereas `SYSDATE` is the actual timestamp at the time that function is called – so the difference would normally be in the milliseconds area, unless you have a really long running procedure.

Comment: And of course you’ll want to do your check in the SELECT statement already, everything else does not make much sense. If you can afford display data not to be accurate to the very second, then you might want to use a specific time interval (like say rounded down to the minute, or five or ten minutes) instead of `NOW` in your WHERE clause, so that the query cache can be used. But this depends on how often the data is read and other factors.

Comment: @CBroe accurate to within second would be better since some of the intervals are only 2 minutes, 30 seconds.  This page https://coderwall.com/p/eslwuw/why-not-to-use-now-in-mysql says "What occurs after the lock is removed is that each statement is then processed by the MySQL server. However, the clock has moved forward at this point and all the NOW() entries will contain a time after the lock was removed. "

Comment: I doubt that what is described on that page does come into play in your scenario here.

Comment: @CBroe It might not...  the problem is, I'm a newbie to this... so I don't know WHY it wouldn't come into play.  The problem is, almost every site I come across explains things so simply that I just can't "get it" (I know that doesn't make sense but it's true), or they assume too much prior knowledge and I can't understand it.  So I was playing it safe...

Comment: 5 hours before the bounty expires.  Have any of us redirected your thinking enough to you get to a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"When they reload the tab it will show if any of the checklist items are ready to be clicked again." -- Let's start by improving on that.  Let's *get rid of the reload tab*.  Each checklist item's "remaining time" can be loaded onto the page upon page load.  A fairly simple JavaScript function can wake up every second, run through the items (even if it is 200 items), check which ones have "timed out", and change the item from Red to Green (or however you want to indicate that "It's time now!").  Meanwhile, each item could even have a countdown timer displayed on it.  Note, also, that pushing the burden onto the users' browsers takes a big load off your server.

Once the user clicks the item, *then* you go back to the server, which goes back into MySQL to reset that one timer.

**So, back to the database design.**

Plan A:  One row per user; 200 columns, one per item.  `UPDATE tbl SET item123 = ... WHERE user_id = 9876;`  However, you would have to 'construct' the SQL because of needing to fabricate the column name: `item123`.

Plan B:  One row per user per item.  `UPDATE tbl SET next = ... WHERE user_id = 9876 AND item_num = 123`.

Either plan would be 'efficient'; it should be easy to handle more than 5K updates per minute.  Plan B would take more **disk space**.

But, there is another query to worry about:  **Loading the page**.  That, as I understand it, involves:  Given a user_id, fetch the 200 (or just 20?) timers for that user.

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE user_id = 9876;`

Plan A (as defined above):  That SELECT would fetch one wide row.

Plan B: That SELECT would fetch 200 (or 20) rows.

Still, both are "efficient", with one proviso:

Plan A's table needs `PRIMARY KEY(user_id)`

Plan B's table needs `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, item_num)`

Keep in mind that a cronjob cannot reach out to a web page.  Hence, this design is "turned around".

Now for some **numbers**.  If you have 1000 users "online" at any given time, and they click an "item" on average once a minute,...  That's 1K UPDATEs and 1K SELECTs to build the reloaded page.  2K/minute is well within the 5K I mentioned.  However, it is pushing the limit -- think about spikes in traffic, etc.  So, there *may* need to be some extra care in how things are implemented.  We can get to that if these numbers make sense.

**Edits**

Since not all users will have all items, let's discuss the use of **space take (or not taken) by unneeded items**.

- Plan A: There is a small overhead for each NULL column.
- Plan B: You don't even need to have the unused rows.  That is, a user would have *up to* 200 rows.  Hence, no 'wasted' space.

**What about increasing the "200"?**

- Plan A: *Downtime* to do ALTER TABLE.  *This is a big drawback to Plan A.*
- Plan B: No schema change needed.

**RAM size and Dataset size?**

If everything can be cached in RAM, then the only I/O is for writing to the transaction log (InnoDB) and for eventually persisting the data to disk.  Even if the number of *active* users is such that *their* rows can be cached in RAM until they log out, that comment about I/O is approximately correct.

If you have more *active* users than can effectively be cached, then the process becomes I/O-bound, and you won't be able to keep up.  This could be solved by (a) more RAM (and increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size) or (b) "sharding" -- spreading users across multiple machines.

1GB VM means innodb_buffer_pool_size should be only 100M, but that might be big enough to handle your projected *active* load.  (As you say, the numbers are fuzzy.)

**Multiple databases?**

One table, not PARTITIONed, in one database.  There is no advantage (as far as I can see) in splitting up by database, tables, or PARTITION.  Sharding (mentioned above) *may* be useful if you grow a lot.  Still, I would beef up the one server first:  Two hardware improvements: more RAM and RAID striping with write cache.  (Those are not needed yet.  It would be better to get metrics on *active* users, click rate, etc, before deciding when/if to beef up the hardware.)

**200 connections limit?**

Is that max_connections = 200?  Or max_user_connections?  Are you using a cloud service that won't let you increase that?

Suggest you disconnect promptly rather than hanging onto the connection, which the user won't hit for another minute anyway.  You can enforce that by setting wait_timeout (or is it interactive_wait_timeout?) to, say, 10 seconds.

Let's try to fix the problem at this level, before resorting to adding "instances".

Comment: The numbers are hard to figure out...  the biggest of the included sites can have as many as 500 users online at once and I figure if I'm lucky up to 25% of those will use my site... so with 200 sites that would be 25,000 users online... but at least half those sites only have 1-15 users online at once so if half is those that would take it down to 14,000.  But now for the part that messes up the math - an unknown number of those users are logged into more than one of those sites at a time.... meaning I have no clue how many of those are unique users.

Comment: But as a guess about how many of those are unique... I'd guess I might have as many as 8000-10,000 users at a time if my site gets as popular as I hope. But, not all those sites will have checklists either... only about 50%-75% will.

Comment: I'm thinking of putting this part into it's own database as my hosting account is limited to 200 concurrent database connections and 1gb database size.  Does any of that info affect your answer? And thank you for such a well written and understandable answer!

Comment: Can't edit my comment... That's 25 databases with those limits... next plan up is unlimited # of databases with same limits.  I have to wonder if splitting the sites up between databases would be the best way of working with those limits?  Since there's this set of checklists, the shared links, and then another set of checklists (that luckily only need stored), goals, and wishlists.

Comment: I just had a thought.... do empty cells take up disk space? If they do, the first design will have a lot of wasted space since a lot of users won't need all the items.

Comment: I'm building on a shared hosting account on godaddy... this is going to take awhile to build and I can't afford vps or dedicated when this is probably going to take 6 months to a year to build with all the learning involved.  My databases are on a separate server than my site (and they aren't even all on the same server as far as I can tell)... 200 max between my server and the database... I KNOW doing this on shared hosting is insane, but it will be awhile before the site is open, and even longer before it hits peak usage. And it looks like B is definitely the way to go on design.

Comment: Is memcache something I should look at?

Comment: No.  Memcached is useful if _most_ of the activity is _reads_.  Keep in mind that any cache needs some way to be refreshed when a _write_ occurs.  As I see it, you have as many writes as reads, maybe more.

Comment: It's now bugging me that there will be hundreds of entries for 1 item just because there are hundreds of users with that item... it does make sense to do it this way because they have different reset times... but what if once an item was checked it stayed checked?  Isn't there some way to do a tree sort of thing or 3d database (if you understand what I mean)?  I'm fairly sure saving to file isn't the way to do it.  Or is this where those confusing foreign keys would come into play?

Comment: The number of entries is less important (to performance) than the number of queries per second (qps) and whether adequate index(es) can be put on the tables to make the queries fast.  Offloading work to JavaScript decreases the qps drastically.  A billion-row (or whatever) table will take disk space, but might perform adequately.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot search 1M * 200 items several times a minute.  So, you need another way to approach the task.

(I think NOW() vs SYS_DATE() is the least of your problems.)

You are using InnoDB, not MyISAM, I hope.  (MyISAM uses table locks, and you won't be able to keep up.)

Let's consider

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    ts TIMESTAMP ... NOT NULL,
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
    d TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL  COMMENT 'D1..D200',
    PRIMARY KEY(timestamp, id),
    INDEX(id)   -- to make AUTO_INCREMENT happy
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

That way, all the queries will be looking at the "beginning" of the table:

```
SELECT d, GROUP_CONCAT(user_id)
    FROM Foo
    WHERE ts < NOW()
    GROUP BY d;
```

That will get all the data for the page, and do it quite efficiently.  Note that, in InnoDB, the data is "clustered" on the `PRIMARY KEY`, hence I made sure that `ts` was the start of the PK.

Since this table will have 200M *rows*, it will be considerably bigger than the table you proposed (at 201M *cells*).  But I am hoping that focusing on the SELECTs will outweigh the size cost.

Since I don't understand the how/when the data is updated I assume all 200 numbers are updated (repeatedly updated?), either 1 at a time (or all 200 at once?), there could be a problem with the effort to do the updates.

Another thing to seriously consider:  Batch the updates.  With normal disks and default configuration, you can do only 100 UPDATEs per second.  Its usually not too hard to get to 1000/sec.  But how many do you need?  This update performance problem exists (in different forms) with either your schema or mine.

Suggest you "do the math" to compute UPDATEs/sec and rows/sec read.

Comment: I'm a newbie to all this, but if I read your answer a few times I might understand it.  I haven't figured out where to look on my hosting account to see if I'm using InnoDB (it's a Linux server if that makes a difference).  There will be a checklist on a user's page (although the each tab will probably only show 10-20 items... I forgot about that part).  The user will click a button to show they finished a task which is when the reset time will be added to the database.  When they reload the tab it will hopefully show if any of the checklist items are ready to be clicked again.

Comment: Added more info to question

Comment: _“You cannot search 1M * 200 items several times a minute”_ – I don’t think that’s the plan here; since those items are shown based on the viewing user, there should not be a problem, assuming proper indexes are in place.

Comment: OK, I goofed.  I would still like to see a back-of-the-envelope estimate of how many of each of INSERT, UPDATE, and SELECT you expect to do per day (or per second).  Also point out how many rows are involved.  Selecting 1 row with a good key is 'nothing', but 10K rows in a single SELECT is a bigger burden on the database.

Comment: Maybe you should re-read my question... I've added more information twice, and I'm pretty sure I give plenty of information.  If I check on pageload (tabload), I will be checking probably 10-20 rows  at the same time... probably separate SELECT's but I don't know if that's really the fastest way, which is why I posted this question.  Each user will only update 1 row per click, and those probably won't be too close together.  It's a daily checklist... did I do 'a' on site '1', did I do 'b' on site '1', etc.  They will mark them off as they finish them.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the following:

Your database should not rely on external runs to become usable again. If your external run fails for whatever reason, it fails silently and your application locks up without any message to the user.

Furthermore, you should use a sane database layout. Most people won't have anywhere near 150 items on their checklist, and some would perhaps want 151.

I would recommend the following data table layout:

```
ItemId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY_KEY auto_increment
UserId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
ItemName VARCHAR (100),
Interval TIME NULL, -- the interval at which the check may be set again
NextCheckAllowed DATETIME NULL -- the datetime the check may be set again
```

Now, whenever someone ticks an item on the list, you can send the itemId to the server, and update `NextCheckAllowed` of that specific item to `TIMEADD(NOW(),Interval)`. Whenever someone reads the list, you will do sth. like

```
SELECT *,NextCheckAllowed>NOW() AS IsChecked 
FROM dataTable WHERE UserId=@UserId
```

and you will be able to provide the user with a list of all his tasks, complete with a boolean checked/unchecked mark.

You should furthermore consider to do most of the calculation client-side, and only check server-side when an update to the database is requested. Client-side calculations are cheap, even with a million or so people, but they can be faked, so before you change anything on the server-side (or before you assume that the person requesting the data has UserId @UserId), you have to run a background check whether this operation is really allowed.

Comment: Trust me, I know my future users... they will have between 5-15 items (depending on the site) for up to maybe 200 sites (although I can't imagine trying to use all 200 sites lol... maybe 20, but I also get bored faster than most of my future users)... for all I know they'll say "these sites are for Monday, these for Tuesday".  At one point I tried to keep up with 30+ of these sites (that's how many existed at the time), and kept forgetting tasks... that's what inspired this project.  Yeah, most of my users won't be obsessed, but I'm trying to plan ahead for the few that are.

Comment: @KatCox Perhaps I misinterpreted your post, but your example database row seems to have 150 `time` columns. Why is that? Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm new to databases and last time I posted a question about table layout I had a different table for each site where the columns would be "userid" and "url_end" for posted links... I was told 1 big table was better for that...